# Axis and Angle of Rotation of 3x3 matrix

Tags: geometry

\begin{pmatrix}
√ 3/2 & -1/4 & √3/4\\ 
1/2 & √3/4 & -3/4\\ 
0 & √3/2 & 1/2
\end{pmatrix}

How do I find the axis and angle of rotation of this matrix?

Comment: Are you sure that your matrix is correct? This matrix corresponds to *more than a simple rotation*. A rotation needs an eigenvalue of one whose eigenvector belongs to the axis of rotation. (A rotation fixes the axis of rotation). Your matrix does not have an eigenvalue of one. Your matrix has determinant $-\frac{1}{8}$. All rotations have $\det(M) = 1$. The negative determinant implies a reflexion and size implies a scale factor of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

The trace of a rotational matrix equals $1+2\cos\phi$, so this extracts the angle. If you take the antisymmetric part of the matrix:

$$A-A^T$$

it looks like

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&-z&y\\z&0&-x \\-y &x &0\end{bmatrix}$$

where $(x,y,z)$ is the axis (not normalized). This vector is actually the axis, multiplied by $2\sin\phi$, which defines the sense of rotation (the sign of the angle).

The inverse of this transformation is the Rodrigues' formula:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula

Of course your matrix first has to be a pure rotational matrix! If it's not, you have to decide what you want anyway. For instance, if you want to present your transformation as a composition of rotation and scaling, you take the polar decomposition.

Comment: apologies, i have now corrected matric. the entry on 2nd row third column was missing a - sign.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the axis $x$ solving the equation $$
   Ax=x
   $$
2. Find the angle looking at $Ax^\perp_1,Ax^\perp_2$ where $x^\perp_{1,2}$ both are orthogonal to $x$ and $x^\perp_1\perp x^\perp_2$

NB: note that you can get $\cos\theta = \frac 12(tr A -1)$ directly, but you don't get the sign of $\theta$.

Comment: Well the sign isn't defined until you specify the axis, because if you flip the axis, you flip the sign.

Comment: @ orion: fir a given axis the sign is not defined with only the value of $\cos\theta$

Comment: apologies, i have now corrected matrix. the entry on 2nd row third column was missing a - sign.